# Can't connect to internet via Ethernet, RTL8111/8168/8411

Tags: networking, ethernet

I just installed Xubuntu on a old machine and I can't connect to internet via Ethernet.

When I do `ifconfig` I get

```
family@PC:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:18:f3:04:ef:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 97  bytes 8206 (8.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 570  bytes 92342 (92.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3936  bytes 238179 (238.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3936  bytes 238179 (238.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
family@PC:~$ dmesg | grep "eth0"
[    2.486036] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168b/8111b at 0x(ptrval), 00:18:f3:04:ef:6a, XID 18000000 IRQ 24
[    2.486039] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 4080 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    2.592180] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth0
```

I manually assigned an IP, now when I look at the IP router it looks like this:

```
family@PC:~$ ip route
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.126 metric 100
```

---

```
family@PC:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.126  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::218:f3ff:fe04:ef6a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:18:f3:04:ef:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 61  bytes 5126 (5.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 396  bytes 49693 (49.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3699  bytes 230145 (230.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3699  bytes 230145 (230.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
family@PC:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for family: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:18:f3:04:ef:6a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.126 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:24 ioport:a800(size=256) memory:ff7ff000-ff7fffff memory:ff7c0000-ff7dffff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:05:04.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=64
       resources: irq:17 memory:ff9fc000-ff9fdfff
family@PC:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
family@PC:~$ host www.ebay.com
Host www.ebay.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does WiFi connect to the Internet, what does the ip route show say

Comment: What did you change to get the "new" ifconfig? fyi: your device is NOT eth0, it's enp2s0. Show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Can you `ping 8.8.8.8`? Can you `host www.ebay.com`? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I manually assigned an IP to get the new ifconfig. The connection is not eth0 it's enp2s0

Comment: Assigning a manual address didn't resolve your problem. How is this laptop connected via its ethernet cable... to a hub/switch/modem/router?

Comment: It's a desktop PC and it's connected to a router

Comment: @heynnema I updated the post with the information you asked

Comment: Have you rebooted the router? Try a DIFFERENT ethernet cable connected to a DIFFERENT lan port on the router. If that doesn't work, plug the ethernet cable DIRECTLY into the cable/dsl modem, reboot BOTH, and see if that works. Does wireless work to the same router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you might as well kill me but the solution to my problem was really simple I had simply connected the ethernet cable to an STB port... Once I had this sort out all I had to do was run

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

restart my PC and everything was good to go. Thanks those who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your computer knows you HAVE an interface, but isn't able to connect to your network. You can see that `ifconfig` has transmit and received some frames

`RX packets 97  bytes 8206 (8.2 KB)`

`TX packets 570  bytes 92342 (92.3 KB)`

So the transmission medium (your Ethernet cabling) is working and there are devices on the other side, but your PC might not be receiving an IP address from your DHCP server. A few things to try include:

1. Turn on DHCP. You can do this graphically by navigating to your Ethernet settings; depending on distro/release you should be presented with the option to obtain an IP address automatically. Or from the CLI, run:

`sudo ifconfig enp2s0 down`

`sudo dhclient enp2s0`

`sudo ifconfig enp2s0 up`

If it says something like "File Exists", that means it was already enabled.

2. Check your router/DHCP Server. Typically on a home network these are one in the same device. First step is to reboot it; if that fails you'll need to log in to its web interface and check that DHCP is enabled and that your client list isn't full, or your PC isn't somehow excluded.
3. Statically assign an IP address. Depending on what your network's addressing scheme is, you can manually assign an IP address with `sudo ifconfig enp2s0 192.168.1.x 255.255.255.0`. replace the first 3 sets of numbers in `192.168.1.x` to match your network. For example, if your router has an IP address of 192.168.25.1, make your PC something like 192.168.25.30 (just make sure the address isn't already taken by another device on your network).

Comment: I managed to establish a connection with the third step but I can't actually access the internet...

Comment: Are you able to communicate with other devices on your network in this manner, just not the internet? If so, run `route add default gw 192.168.1.x` where `192.168.1.x` is the address of your router.

Comment: No I am not able to communicate with other devices in my network, though my router has the Mac address of the computer listed among the connected devices

Comment: What is the IP address of your router? Am I right assuming this is a home network?

Comment: You are right and the IP is the classic 192.168.1.1

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: Xubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: I'm still unfamiliar with the Netplan scheme that 18.04 uses, but you could probably follow https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/ for a quick guide on configuring your address that way. This would allow you to enter more details at once and would give you errors about misconfigurations.

Comment: The article you sent me (I might be wrong) it's for Ubuntu server and the configuration file is called 50-cloud-init.yaml whereas mine is called 01-network-manager-all.yaml... What it says in the section under "Configure Network Interfaces With NetworkManager" is exactly my case but it doesn't actually give me any troubleshooting